# Comparing two variables. Second contains first

Tags: bash

```bash
var_1="hi"
var_2="bye,hi,hello"
if [[ "$var_1" == *"$var_2"* ]];
then
   echo "value of var_1 in var_2";
else
   echo "sad =(";
fi
```

I would like check second variable contains first.
That prints "Sad =(", why?

Comment: It's a typo: you should revert var1 and var2 as it's `var_1` that should be into `var_2`

Comment: `if [[ "$var_2" =~ "$var_1" ]];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition checks that $var_1 consists of $var_2, possibly preceded and followed by something. But it's the other way round.

```
if [[ $var_2 = *"$var_1"* ]]
#          ~          ~
```

Comment: it should be `==` not `=` but yes (it's a typo question)

Comment: @Elikill58: Why? They both work (and it's documented).

Comment: it will change the variable, no ?

Comment: @Elikill58 No. Read choroba's comment again.

Comment: @Elikill58 perhaps you're thinking of `awk` where `x=3` is an assignment and `x==3` is a test/conditional ... ?